# combining geom_area with factor x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with factorial x axis (not convertible in value ) and I'd like to
plot a stacked area chart

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = rep(paste0(letters,formatC(1:26, width=2, flag="0")),2),
                 y = rep(runif(26)+1:26,2),
                 z = c(rep("a",26),rep("b",26)))

df %>% ggplot(aes(x= x, y=y)) + 
  geom_area(aes(colour = z, fill = z))
```

what I get is a bar chart:
[image]

All the solution I have found to this problem involve a conversion of the x axis value (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343494/ggplot2-geom-area-with-factorial-x-axis))

Is there any other way to obtain a stacked chart area with factorial axis?
How can I hide the first area ("b")?

Thank you very much

Comment: THat's definitely not a bar chart. And it's stacked.  How is it you expect the letters to be treated given that the variable is a factor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x= x, y=y)) + 
  geom_area(aes(colour = z, group=z, fill = z))
```

Comment: thank you very much. What I get is different from what I expected but I corrected your code using position = "stack" and it worked

Comment: My bad, I'll fix it... What I did was a 100% stacked chart

Comment: can you please explain what was the problem  with my code?

Comment: You just forgot to `group` by the factors in `z`. I'll update the answer with the code just like as you wrote.